# Using Edge.js from a C# console application

Tags: c#, node.js, edge.js

I'm trying to do something that seems very simple, yet I cannot get it to work. I've installed Edge.js via nuget and I want to execute a piece of Javascript from inside a C# console application. The code from my `public static void main` is below:

```
Task.Run(async () => {
    Console.WriteLine(
        await Edge.Func("return function() { return 'hello world'; }")(null).Result
    );
}).Wait();
```

I run the application and all it does is hangs.

I've tried this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Edge.Func("return function() { return 'hello'; }")(null).Result);
```

Same result. And this too...

```
var task = Edge.Func("return function() { return 'hello'; }")(null);
await task;
Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
```

Same result. Hanging...

I also tried `RunSynchronously()` rather than awaiting, which gave me an `InvalidOperationException`.

I followed the documentation [here](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-call-nodejs-from-c).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the callback to send the string. You can't just return the string. See:

```
Edge.Func(@"
        return function (data, callback) {
            callback(null, 'hello world');
        }
    ");
```

You have to follow this structure when using Edge:

[image: Edge]