# How to resolve Edge.Func hanging?

Tags: c#, node.js, edgejs

I'm evaluating Edge.Js for use in an existing project, but I'm running into an issue with calling Edge.Func. For projects that ***aren't*** a console application, it hangs (no exception thrown) on the `Edge.Funct(` call (e.g.WebAPI or Test projects).

```
    // Next line hangs
    var func = Edge.Func(@"
return function (data, callback) {
    callback(null, 'hello world');
}");
```

I have a test sln here: https://github.com/cumminsjp/edgete

If I drop that same code into a console app--it works and I get the expected `hello world` back from the function.

I've seen related discussions / issues:
https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/215
https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/373
[Using Edge.js from a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190524/using-edge-js-from-a-c-sharp-console-application)

But I'm not convinced that I haven't mis-configured something or that I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a working Edge.Js console example and I copied it to the test sln folder where I was experiencing the problem.  All of a sudden, the console app also hung on the `Edge.Func` call. Eventually, I figured out that it was the presence of a junction (at any point in the full path) that causes the problem.

My solution was contained in a sub-directory of a directory that was a junction, which Edge.Js does not seem to tolerate.

```
<DIR>
<DIR>
<DIR>
<DIR>
<DIR>
<JUNCTION>  <-- Edge.Js doesn't like
<DIR>
<DIR>
```

If I either copy that sln directory to a normal directory (or find the physical directory the junction is pointing to an open the sln from there), both the console example and test project could successfully call `Edge.Func`

Comment: That was really, **really** helpful. Thanks for posting your answer.